# Sequential pipes between two children and a parent in C/UNIX

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, parent-child

I was trying to solve an example in operating systems book about inter-process communication and pipes but I ran into few difficulties.It asks me to find the time in parent and then print it out with child no1.After some sleeping child no 2 should print the time information which is found in child no 1.And after some sleeping parent should print the time information which is found in child no 2.So I thought I should create 3 pipes since I need to pass the time information 3 times.I tried to design one of them between child one and child two but I am not sure if I did it correctly.One other problem is that I dont know how to print the time.When I try to print it with printf %d it gives me 0.Can anyone help me for passing the time from parent to child number1 and print it so I can test my program?Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include<signal.h>



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct timeval t1;
    struct timeval t2;
    struct timeval t3;
    int firstchild,secondchild;
    firstchild=fork();
        int mypipe[2];
    int mypipe2[2];
    int mypipe3[2];

        if(pipe(mypipe) == -1) {
          perror("Pipe failed");
          exit(1);
        }

        if(firstchild == 0)            //first child
        {

       close(STDOUT_FILENO);  //closing stdout
            dup(mypipe[1]);         //pipewrite is replaced.
        sleep(3);               
            close(mypipe[0]);       //pipe read is closed.
            close(mypipe[1]);      //pipe write is closed   

        }else{
    secondchild=fork();        //Creating second child

        if(secondchild == 0)            //2nd child
        {
            close(STDIN_FILENO);   //closing stdin
            dup(mypipe[0]);         //pipe read
        sleep(6);
            close(mypipe[1]);       //pipe write    is closed.
            close(mypipe[0]);      //pipe read is closed.   

        }else{            //Parent

    gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);
    printf("\n Time is %d ",gettimeofday(&t1,NULL));
    sleep(9);
    printf("\n Parent:sent a kill signal to child one with id %d ",secondchild-1);
    printf("\n Parent:sent a kill signal to child two with id %d ",secondchild);
    kill(secondchild-1,SIGKILL);    
    kill(secondchild,SIGKILL);
    exit(1);}}
        close(mypipe[0]);
        close(mypipe[1]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Making question a bit more clear : I think dup works correctly. What I need is that a working pipe between parent and first children and a way to print the time(which is calculated in parent)with first children so that I can test both of them work and continue to code. I am open to use pipes with different style as long as it works.Using dup was the thing I saw in the book so thats the thing I used

Comment: Did you read the manpages for *any* of the functions you are using? what exactly do you hope to gain from `dup(mypipe[0]);`? Do you not think the return value *might* have some significance?

Comment: Just a comment: in standard English writing one puts a space after punctuation marks like `. , ? ! ; :`.  Your post doesn't do that, and it makes it very hard to read.

Comment: @EOF I agree that the question is a bit unclear. But I think that `dup` is ok as it is replacing stdin with `mypipe[0]`. That works because `STDIN_FILENO` is closed before the `dup`. It relies on the fact that dup "uses the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor" (quote from the man page). I also didn't know that technique and learnt about it recently on SO.

Comment: I think dup works correctly. What I need is that a working pipe between parent and first children and a way to print the time(which is calculated in parent)with first children so that I can test both of them work and continue to code.

Comment: @kaylum: That's insane. There is a *reason* why `dup()` returns the file descriptor, and why `dup2()` was introduced. The lowest-numbered file-descriptor you expected could have already been reused by another thread, or even by a signal handler. That kind of programming is *horrendously* bad practice.

Comment: @EOF I personally always use `dup2`. But I've been corrected several times on SO when I made the same comment as you. And I sort of see the point. The `dup` method would not work for all file descriptors. But stdin and stdout are special in that their file descriptor values are posix defined. Anyway, whether you agree with the practice or not, it's good to know that some people will hold that view.

Answer (score 0):

> I should create 3 pipes since I need to pass the time information 3
>   times.I tried to design one of them between child one and child two
>   but I am not sure if I did it correctly.
>
> ```
>     firstchild=fork();
>         int mypipe[2];
>     …
>         if(pipe(mypipe) == -1) …
> ```

You didn't quite. You must create the pipe before the `fork()`, because otherwise the child cannot access (the read end of) the parent's pipe.

> passing the time from parent to child number1

Parent:

```
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    write(mypipe[1], &t1, sizeof t1);
```

First child:

```
        read(mypipe[0], &t1, sizeof t1);
```

> I dont know how to print the time.When I try to print it with printf
>   %d it gives me 0.
>
> ```
>     printf("\n Time is %d ",gettimeofday(&t1,NULL));
> ```

You didn't print the time, but what the `gettimeofday()` function returns, which is 0. Correct:

```
        printf(" Time is %ld\n", (long)t1.tv_sec);
```